# Unity 3D: Transition of Animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I am new to Unity3D and I was working on the following tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXpi1czz5NA

It all worked fine.

I wanted to add functionality where if the skeleton hits something with his sword, he will real back like he's taking damage. Sort of a poorman's way of having his sword collide with objects.

But I've found it doesn't work correctly. I seem to either have a choice to cause a 'hit' to put it into an infinite loop, or to ignore the hit all together. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class chase : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    static Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Debug.Log (anim.ToString ());
        //Debug.Log ("Start Update");
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        //Debug.Log ("Distance: " + direction.magnitude.ToString ());
        float angle = Vector3.Angle (direction, this.transform.forward);
        //Debug.Log ("Angle: " + angle.ToString ());
        //Debug.Log(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Damage"));

        // Get top animation currently running
        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

        if (Vector3.Distance (player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 && angle < 120 && !stateInfo.IsName ("Attack") && !anim.GetBool("Hit")) {

            direction.y = 0;
            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (direction), 0.1f);

            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
            if (direction.magnitude > 2) {
                this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.03f);
                anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
                anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
            } else {
                anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
                anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
            }
        }
        else{
            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the sword collision script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordCollision : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator anim;

    // We just collided with an object
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {
        int layer = collider.gameObject.layer;
        anim = this.GetComponentInParent<Animator> ();
        //Debug.Log (anim.ToString ());
        if (layer != LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor") && layer != LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Monster")) {
            Debug.Log ("Sword Hit something:" + collider.name.ToString());
            Debug.Log (LayerMask.LayerToName(layer));

            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("Hit", true); // kicks off damage state
        }
    }

}
```

I setup the transitions to attack and damage animations to "has exit time" so that they would play all the way through. The other transitions do not have this so they can be interrupted right away upon a 'hit' taking place.

The problem seems to be that after the sword collision script registers a hit and sets the "Hit" boolean to "true" (to kick off the damage animation) that the chase script immediately cancels it, so the hit never takes place. (i.e. anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);)

However, if I comment out that line, then the damage animation does take place, but obviously it gets stuck in a loop because now I have nothing to shut it off.

This was causing me to pull my hair out because the attack animation is setup almost identically. But I think the reason that one works correctly is because the boolean "isAttacking" gets set to 'true' continually in the chase script until the animation really starts. Because the damage animation is kicked off from a different script, there doesn't seem to be an easy way for me to be sure the animation begins before allowing the chase script to change the boolean value for "hit".

Is there some way to do that? Like a delay or something that guarantees the animation changes states. Or maybe a way to check for when the 'damage' animation is completed before changing the boolean value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I finally came up with. Kinda hacky in my opinion. I still feel I'm not doing this in the best way.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class chase : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    static Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Debug.Log (anim.ToString ());
        //Debug.Log ("Start Update");
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        //Debug.Log ("Distance: " + direction.magnitude.ToString ());
        float angle = Vector3.Angle (direction, this.transform.forward);
        //Debug.Log ("Angle: " + angle.ToString ());
        //Debug.Log(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Damage"));

        // Get top animation currently running
        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

        if (anim.GetBool("Hit") && !stateInfo.IsName ("Damage")) {
            print ("keep going");
            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("Hit", true);
        }
        else if (Vector3.Distance (player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 && angle < 120 && !stateInfo.IsName ("Attack") && !stateInfo.IsName ("Damage")) {

            direction.y = 0;
            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (direction), 0.1f);

            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
            if (direction.magnitude > 2) {
                print ("Following");
                //this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.03f);
                anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
                anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
            } else {
                print ("Attacking");
                anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
                anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
            }
        } 
        else {
            print("Back to Idle");
            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
            anim.SetBool ("Hit", false);
        }
    }
}
```